# Ratchet + AWS EC2 + SSL + ProxyPass -> Invalid Status Line

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, amazon-ec2, websocket

I'm trying to create a video chat using ratchet with laravel and it worked fine on localhost but when I deployed it on an EC2 instance, it needed some configuration. First, I can access my app with HTTPS, it works fine. I can connect to my Ratchet WebSocket server via ws and HTTP but HTTPS requires wss and I can't figure out how to make it work. I've used ProxyPass since it seems to be the answer for most people : (etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf)

ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://fake-domain.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com:8181/

And my client side JS code : var socket = new WebSocket('wss://fake-domain.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/wss2/');

But this returns : 'Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line'
and it doesn't even change anything if I run my Ratchet server or not.

PHP code (I managed to put it in a laravel command so it's easier):

```
public function handle()
    {
        $server = IoServer::factory(
            new WsServer(
                new VideoController()
            ),
            8181
        );

        $server->run();
    }
```

I can telnet fake-domain.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com 8181, it says it works.
I saw that it could come from the apache version so I updated my apache and php version : php -v = 7.2.8 httpd -v = 2.4.34
I accept all traffic in the security groups and port 80, 443 and 8181 are open.

What am I missing?
Thank's ;)

UPDATE : I figured out that I wasn't starting the socket server correctly, I forgot to put "sudo" before my command, but now it gives me another error:

```
UnexpectedValueException  : $request can not be null

  at /var/app/current/vendor/cboden/ratchet/src/Ratchet/WebSocket/WsServer.php:109
    105|      * {@inheritdoc}
    106|      */
    107|     public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn, RequestInterface $request = null) {
    108|         if (null === $request) {
  > 109|             throw new \UnexpectedValueException('$request can not be null');
    110|         }
    111|
    112|         $conn->httpRequest = $request;
    113|
```

UPDATE 2 :

I think I've just found the solution, I think I didn't integrate Ratchet correctly with Laravel and maybe the solution is here : https://gist.github.com/Mevrael/6855dd47d45fa34ee7161c8e0d2d0e88
I'm going to try tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I've finnaly found how to make it work!! It was just an error in the load balancer, the port 8181 was SSL and when I changed to TCP it worked!!

Comment: Can you please guide through setting up the load balancer? I can't connect to the websocket here. I'm using Ratchet too